# Trust device not possible because "General -> Device Manager" is missing

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to reset some variables that were being saved on my game, and after deleting my game and re-installing it, asked me for the "this device isn't trusted. Go to General -> Device Manager" to solve it" again. But for some reason, it isn't available anymore. I tried rebooting my iPhone, restarting XCode, and nothing works. Every time I go to Settings -> General I have the same settings over and over again.

Can anyone help me? How come was this working before, the option was being shown in Settings, and now it doesn't?

> Extra Info: I'm using iOS 9.3.3 Model: MKRJ2LL/A iPhone 6S

Thanks in advance, this is so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Check your Internet (your iphone)
Hope it help

Comment: My internet is fine, that was one of the things i checked too. Thanks for replying tho. :/ I can't believe this is happening, i think this is the stupidest thing ever from Apple... why would it bugged SO BAD??? just for removing the app from my phone and installing it again??? doesn't make sense... Android on that rules.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. After a few more hours, ended up being the provision profiles under XCode being in conflict for my device, I even had duplicated ones. And I also downloaded the iOS Developer and iOS Distributor certificates from iTunes Connect and added them.